# How to find the cofactor of a specific row and column?

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array

Alright so, I'm trying to find the cofactor of a specific row and column

Let's say I have this matrix:

```
1  2  3
4  5  6
7  8  9
```

and I want the  cofactor of the position `0,0`

the result would be:

```
5  6
8  9
```

However, my code generates always a `0` on a spot depending on what I do with the values `i , k`
`n , m` (watch the code below)

this codes generates the following matrix:

```
5  0
8  9
```

btw I got the result matrix from BlueJ, I'll leave a simple print all elements in matrix code below the original code in case you don't want to use the debbuger

here's the code:

```java
public int[][] adjointMatrix(int matrixRow, int matrixColumn, int[][] matrix)
        throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException {
    if (matrixColumn >= matrix.length || matrixRow >= matrix[0].length) {
        throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }
    int[][] Adjoint = new int[matrix.length - 1][matrix[0].length - 1];
    int m = 0;
    int n = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        if (i == matrixRow) {
            continue;
        }
        for (int k = 0; k < matrix[i].length; k++) {
            if (k == matrixColumn) {
                continue;
            }
            Adjoint[m][n] = matrix[k][i];
            if (m < Adjoint.length - 1) {
                m++;
            }
        }
        if (n < Adjoint[0].length - 1) {
            n++;
        }
    }
    return Adjoint;
}
```

```java
adjointMatrix(0, 0, new int[][]{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}});
```

print the whole matrix:

```java
// print it somewhere in a class
for (int i = 0; i < matrixname.length; i++) {
    for (int k = 0; k < matrixname[0].length; k++) {
        System.out.print(matrixname[i][k] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should've been `Adjoint[m][n] = matrix[i][k]` instead of `Adjoint[m][n] = matrix[k][i]`. `i` is the row index counter and `k` is the column index counter.

Also, you need to switch the row to the next one when `n` is at the end of the corresponding row. Then you start from `m` as `m + 1` and `n` as `0`.

Here's your fixed `adjointMatrix()` function snippet:

```
public int[][] adjointMatrix(int matrixRow, int matrixColumn, int[][] matrix)  
    throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException 
    {
        if (matrixColumn >= matrix.length || matrixRow >= matrix[0].length) {
            throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException();
        }
        int[][] Adjoint = new int[matrix.length - 1][matrix[0].length - 1];
        int m = 0;
        int n = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < matrix.length;i++) {
            if (i == matrixRow) {
                continue;
            }
            for(int k = 0; k < matrix[i].length;k++) {
                if(k == matrixColumn) {
                    continue;
                }
                Adjoint[m][n] = matrix[i][k];
                if (n == Adjoint[0].length - 1) {
                    m++;
                    n = 0;
                } else {
                    n++;
                }
            }
        }
        return Adjoint;
    }
```

But you can write the for-loop part in a much simpler way in the following way:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < matrix.length;i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix[0].length; ++j) {
            if (i != matrixRow && j != matrixColumn) {
                Adjoint[m][n++] = matrix[i][j];
                if (n == Adjoint[m].length) {
                    n = 0;
                    ++m;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) to iterate over the indices of this matrix, [`filter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#filter(java.util.function.IntPredicate)) out the specified *row* and *column* and return back the *cofactor* matrix:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] matrix = {
            {1, 2, 3},
            {4, 5, 6},
            {7, 8, 9}};

    int[] position = {0, 0};

    int[][] cofactor = cofactor(matrix, position);

    Arrays.stream(cofactor).map(Arrays::toString).forEach(System.out::println);
    // [5, 6]
    // [8, 9]
}
```

```java
public static int[][] cofactor(int[][] matrix, int[] position) {
    return IntStream.range(0, matrix.length)
            .filter(i -> i != position[0])
            .mapToObj(i -> matrix[i])
            .map(row -> IntStream.range(0, row.length)
                    .filter(j -> j != position[1])
                    .map(j -> row[j])
                    .toArray())
            .toArray(int[][]::new);
}
```